# How do I search for particular key values in postgres jsonb columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, jsonb

I want to get all the rows which have particular *key-value* pairs as received in the input. For. e.g. Consider below data:-

```
CREATE TABLE places(id int, place jsonb) ;
insert into places values (1, '{"country": {"name": "Brazil", "speak_portuguese": true, "river": "amazon"}}');
insert into places values (2, '{"name": "USA", "speak_portuguese": false, "river": "missisipi"}');
insert into places values (3, '{"continent": "South America", "speak_portuguese": true, "river": "amazon"}');
```

The table data looks as below:-

[image]

Now, if I get below *key-value* in input, then rows 1 and 3 should appear in result as the key-value pairs are present in row 1 and 3.

```
{
  "speaks_portuguese": true,
  "river": "amazon"
}
```

I am trying using jsonb_path_exists but having a hard time. Can someone help?

Note: the keys can appear at any level of nesting (e.g. country->state->city etc) and one row can have data of multiple places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As those values appear at different paths, you can use an `or` condition:

```
select *
from places
where place @> '{"speak_portuguese": true, "river": "amazon"}'
  or place -> 'country' @> '{"speak_portuguese": true, "river": "amazon"}'
```

If you don't know the level and if you are using Postgres 12, you can use a JSON path expression:

```
select *
from places
where place @@ '$.**.speak_portuguese == true && $.**.river == "amazon"'
```

Comment: keys can appear at any level of nesting.

Comment: this smells like bad data structure

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, this is what I was looking for. Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu this is just to show example of my use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from places 
where (place->'speak_portuguese')::boolean is true 
   or  (place->'country'->'speak_portuguese')::boolean
```